# How can I get Google Voice Actions to recognize monetary amounts?

Tags: nexus-4, 4.3-jelly-bean, google-voice-actions

I'm using a Nexus 4 running Android 4.3. I would like to be able to have Google Voice Actions recognize monetary amounts properly when adding a reminder, for example. Currently the best output I have been able to get is "$123 45 cents", rather than "$123.45". I have tried phrases such as "one hundred twenty-three dollars and 45 cents", "one hundred twenty-three point four five", "one hundred twenty-three period four five" (which became "123. 45"), and more. Is there some speech format I need to be observing to make this work, and if not, is there a way that I can train or otherwise force Google Voice Actions into recognizing these monetary amounts?

Comment: Note: I tried to use the tag 4.3-jelly-bean but I wasn't allowed so I used 4.2 instead.

Comment: Changed the tag to 4.3 :)